# Cufon Font Replacement Problem in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cufon, font-replacement

I just installed cufon on my wordpress but it is spacing out all my paragraphs.. like this..

does anyone know how i can fix that?

http://singlecutbeer.com/2011/07/hello-world-2/

that space between each paragraph was not there before the font-replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cufon can be very hard to style, the easiest way to do it is to choose the "complete" option when you generate the font. I would recommend using:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: font;
    src: url('font.ttf');
}
```

and cufon as a fallback for IE7-8

All the best,
Marten

Answer (score 0):

Building on moffepoffe's answer, use the font-face generator at [font squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator). Be sure to check your licenses, but technically a great solution.